# I'm getting "Cannot generate the next number for the AR Last Reference Number sequence" error when adding payment for sales order through web API

Tags: acumatica

When I was trying to add payment to a sales order through web service API, I got "PX.Data.PXSetPropertyException: Error: An error occurred while processing the field Payment Ref. : CS Error #30: Cannot generate the next number for the AR Last Reference Number sequence..". The code is as follows:

```
  AR302000Content AR302000 = context.AR302000GetSchema();
  context.AR302000Clear();

  List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();


  //add header info
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = " <NEW>", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.ReferenceNbr });
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Payment", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.Type, Commit = true });
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "A123456", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.Customer });
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "MAIN", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.Location });
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "CreditCard", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.PaymentMethod });
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "300.00", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.PaymentAmount});
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "T123456", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.PaymentRef, Commit = true });
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "99000001", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.CashAccount });

  cmds.Add(AR302000.OrdersToApply.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "00001234", LinkedCommand = AR302000.OrdersToApply.OrderNbr });
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = AR302000.OrdersToApply.OrderType });
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "300.00", LinkedCommand = AR302000.OrdersToApply.OrderTotal });
  cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "300.00", LinkedCommand = AR302000.OrdersToApply.AppliedToOrder });

  cmds.Add(AR302000.Actions.Save);

  AR302000Content[] AR302000content = context.AR302000Submit(cmds.ToArray());
```

I checked my "numbering sequences" configuration and it looks like the only payment related numbering sequence is "ARPAYMENT", which was correct and plus I believe this "ARPAYMENT" is for "ReferenceNbr" anyway.

There doesn't seem to be a numbering sequence for "PaymentRef", which seems to be what the error message was complaining about. Based on the "help" document, this "Payment Ref" should be able to accept a given string, which I did but seems not working...

Anybody knows what could be wrong?

Comment: this info could be helpful http://forum.acumatica.com/forum/acumatica-reseller-and-isv-community/development-and-customization/743-api-examples?p=2811#post2811

Comment: tried adding through UI? No error encountering there?

Comment: @Hybridzz, when I manually created payment on "Payment and Application" screen, I got a red warning "CS Error #30: Cannot generate the next number for the AR Last Reference Number sequence."at the field "Payment Ref."  when I chose an existing customer in "Customer" field; however, when I continued to enter something in the field, that error disappeared. It seems to me there is some configuration to set this field as a "auto-generate" field, however, it could be manually entered, however, it only works for manual data entry but not through web service API.

Comment: "when I chose an existing customer in "Customer" field; however, when I continued to enter something in the field, that error disappeared". In this case, can you try to add commit = true like the customer field and the field you mentioned in your comment.... eg:
 cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "A123456", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.Customer, Commit = true });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the problem - when I created payment, as part of the mandatory requirements, I assigned a cash account, which was associated with one of the "Payment method" - Credit Card, however, for some reason, in that cash account page, "Credit Card" payment method was specified as "AR - Suggest Next Number", which I have no idea about what it means, to be honest. After I unchecked that checkbox, everything became OK. I guess that checkbox means "Payment Ref" field on "Payment and Application" screen needs to be auto-generated, but it's really confusing as there is nowhere mentioning "Payment Ref.".

Anyway, the problem has been resolved and thanks for all of the responses!